# ASIHTTPRequest - Exclude charset from Content-Type header

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to do a file upload.
How can I remove the charset from Content-Type header?

So it will look like this

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryH7RS1ABXkiKv7HSp
```

And not

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=iso-8859-1; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryH7RS1ABXkiKv7HSp
```

That charset is causing the server to throw a 400 error.

Right now I have it working by removing it from the ASIHTTPrequest codebase itself, but wondering if there is a cleaner way to do that.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

The current code seems to always add a charset part.

Perhaps there's a value you can set the charset to that the server will accept?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. Here is what I have found: [link](http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest/browse_thread/thread/739e01e3b065f543/1fd937749e7cde27?pli=1)

See the last answer on that thread. You can find there how to remove "charset" from the header.